# After upgrade still showing Ubuntu 15.10 instead of 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, sudo, do-release-upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 using this command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` but after upgrading and installation it is still showing Ubuntu 15.10. Even I saw it downloading the Ubuntu 16.04 and also installing it after which it asked me restart but after restart I saw that it was still Ubuntu 15.10.
This very sad !!!
Anyone out here to solve this mystery.

```
LSB Version:      core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECsT1.png)

However I get this info, but I swear I everything was updated and also installed, it took me nearly 2 hours!

Comment: Which version you upgraded from?

Comment: from Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: But I saw that it completed the installation of the upgraded version and then requested me to restart.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me numerous times.

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Cycle through those commands until there are no more updated and upgrades.  When there are no more updates and upgrades the **upgrade** commands would have this as the output:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**Note:**

On rare occasions I have had to rerun the `sudo do-release-upgrade` a second time... so rare that I didn't include it in the original message.

Comment: sudo apt-get update - All packages are up to date and Upgrade is showing 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and  0 not upgraded.

Comment: That is one of the three commands you should cycle through.  Keep cyclying though the three commands until both **upgrade** and **dist-upgrade** gives the same output as your current comment.

Comment: No use, I tried doing it.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dist-upgrade`?

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Most likely I should infer the answer, but I have to ask, since you didn't mention it... did you run **all three commands**?  There's one additional, but I wouldn't run it before having run all three of the above and not having any available updates.

Comment: Yes, the update showed `Reading package lists... Done                                                  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.`

Comment: The `sudo apt-get upgrade` showed `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: I'm going to infer that you have run the first one: `sudo apt update`... all three of the commands.  The one that I didn't include because it's rare that I have had to do this one, is to run this again: `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: I would perform a clean install as last result.  I have found this a very rare necessity, and to warrant a lot of time in getting my settings back.

Comment: The only time I have needed a clean install is when performing experiments where I installed something that corrupted the system's functionality.  Your system doesn't appear to be corrupted, and appears to be sufficiently functionally to spend a few commands to resolve the issue.

Comment: Just want to know if my PC configuration is ideal for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu 16.10 [link](saumyainc.com/hardware_info.html)

Comment: I recently upgraded a 5 year old computer from 13.04 to 16.04.  It had just the minimum recommended requirement.  It has a fraction of the power of your computer.  It only has two gigs.  It appears to run 16.04 better than it was running the obsolete OS.  That was one of the computers where I had to cycle thought the commands in my answer to get it fully upgraded.  Did you rerun the `sudo do-release-upgrade` again?  I added the command to the answer.

Comment: Yes. Now it is showing that I can upgrade. But this same thing happened but there was no update. I would better do a clean installation of 16.04.

Comment: Starting over fresh can remove just about any issue.   The last result comes quicker for some than others.  You absolutely won't see any of the 15.10 packages and configurations in the fresh installation.

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of the `sudo do-release-upgrade` including the command, to your question?